# Use of Mathematica to put equation into vector form

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, computational-geometry

Is there a way to put the following equation of a line into vector form using *Mathematica* (or a *Mathematical* package)?

$\displaystyle y=\frac{cos(s_n)-cos(s_{n+1})}{sin(s_{n+1})-sin(s_n)}(x-sin(s_n))-cos(s_n)$

Comment: `v[t_] := {(whatever (t - Sin@kk) - Cos@kk) , t}`?

Comment: Something like this? `In[33]:= Normal[CoefficientArrays[y == m*x + b, {x, y}]]

Out[33]= {-b, {-m, 1}}` (Always helps to provide a specific example of input along with the desired output.)